# Returning an element from a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn lisp and as i'm making my first steps i got stuck.
How can i get c element form following list:  `(a b (c.d))`

I've tried: `(caar (last '(a b (c.d))))` but it returns c.d and not only c
This however works if there are spaces between c, . , d ie: `(caar (last '(a b (c . d))))`

The problem i'm trying to resolves has the list specified without spaces. Can that be done or it's a typo in the exercise?

Thanks.

**LE**: Uisng GNU Clisp http://clisp.cons.org/
Is it possible that the issue it's caused by the implementation?

Comment: Sounds like a typo.  What Lisp are you using?

Comment: how is this question different from the other one you already posted?

Comment: i'm really new to lisp, first lesson and i'm just trying to understand so the question seemed different to me :-?? sorry if it was similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is right, it's a typo (or maybe a really bad font?) in the exercise.

In Lisp (Common Lisp and Scheme are the two I tested just now, I don't know about Clojure), [nearly] the only divisions between symbols are spaces and parentheses. Even though . is used as literal syntax for `cons`, if you type `'(c.d)`, you get one symbol in a list, not two symbols in a cons cell.

For example,

```
'c.d     ; is one symbol
'(c . d) ; is two symbols in a single cons cell
'((c)d)  ; is two symbols, the first in a nested list
```

Edit: Since you are using Common Lisp, here is [the list of relevant characters](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_ad.htm) and [the reader algorithm](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_b.htm). To summarise, `(` and `)` are *terminating characters*, while `.` is not. CLisp is performing according to the Common Lisp spec.

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you have a typo in the exercise.

The (c . d) is a cons cell shown with dotted pair notation.

Here is a link that has more on this http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DottedPairNotation